# ruby instance variable not initialized

Tags: ruby, clipboard

I'm really new to ruby. Using ruby 2.4.6p354 on a mac, I have a simple program that copies all of the text from a file and outputs it to the clipboard using the [clipboard gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/clipboard).

The program works but when I run it I get the following warning:

> warning: instance variable @implementation not initialized

I've searched for an answer to this but I can't find anything that refers to this problem specifically. I believe this has something to do with how the clipboard gem is being used but I'm not sure.

Here's the entire code of my program:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
require 'clipboard'

Clipboard.copy File.read("path_to_file/file.txt")
```

If someone can let me know why this is happening and tell me how to fix it so I don't get this warning when I run my program I would appreciate it.

Comment: This works for me.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev does it give you the warning I listed when you run it?

Comment: Nope, no warnings.

Comment: Ah, I see, it's the `-w`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the commandline parameter for your ruby:

```
-w              turn warnings on for your script
```

It makes this line raise that error:

```
return @implementation if @implementation
```

There's nothing wrong with this line. The warning can be ignored.

But if it was your code that triggered it, you could fix it by initializing the instance variable in your initializer. Even by setting it to `nil`.

Comment: ah, that makes sense. I did see some answers that talked about initializing the variable to `nil` but because I didn't declare the variable myself that is what made me think it was part of the clipboard gem and I didn't know if I initialized it myself if it would screw something up downstream. Thank you very much for the info. As promised, upvoted and marked as accepted answer.